# Using javax.inject.Provider in place of <lookup-method>

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am trying to see how i can use `javax.inject.Provider` in place of Spring `<lookup-method>`. here is my code

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<Source,Target>{
   @Autowired
    private Provider<Target> targetBean;

    protected abstract Target createTarget();
    public Provider<Target> getTargetBean() {
          return this.targetBean;
   }

}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<ObjectA, ObjectB>{

  @Override
   protected ObjectB createTarget()
    {
      return this.targetBean.get();  
    }
}
```

But when i am running this code, i am getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [java.lang.Object] is defined: expected single matching bean but found // list of all beans
```

I know, my understanding of `Provider` is not right, but my question is, do i need to provide

```
  @Autowired
  private Provider<Target> targetBean;
```

In each implementation class or is there something i am doing totally wrong?
I was assuming that since i am passing type of object to Abstract class, Provider will able to find type of bean which is being requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Prototype
    {
    }

@Component
public class Singleton
    {    
    @Autowired
    Provider<Prototype> prototype;

    public Prototype createPrototype()
        {
        return this.prototype.get();
        }
    }

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Factory
    {
    // The ComponentScan does the job
    }

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { Factory.class })
public class SingletonPrototypeTest
    {    
    @Autowired
    Singleton singleton;

    @Test
    public void testFoo()
        {
        Assert.assertTrue(this.singleton.createPrototype() != this.singleton.createPrototype());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've just realized I totally ignored in my answer the generics part and it is mainly the point of the question.